# Woocommerce update cart vía Ajax without click method

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

Is there another way to update the cart totals (ajax update) on the cart page without using the click method?

```
$("[name='update_cart']").trigger("click");
```

On the checkout page is possible update the order review:

```
$(document.body).trigger("update_checkout");
```

Scenario:

I have customized the cart page, including a form to allow users to add productos via sku through Ajax.

When I proces the update cart callback and I get the ajax response I would like to refresh the list of products of the cart and the totals (some jQuery method like in the checkout page). In the same way that happens when you modify the quantity of a product and click the button to update the cart.

Comment: You could look at what WooCommerce does in the `update_cart_action` function. Copy the actions they execute within this function and make a custom function. This custom function could be triggered with Ajax at any moment you wish.

Comment: Is it possible when you select any product or item, you should  be updating your cart total!

Comment: What action do you wish to use instead?

Comment: I tried to explain myself better in the question.